# "More data is available" when reading from a FileStream

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-xp, filestream, handle

I'm reading data from an external drive (LTO) where the blocksize to read is defined by calling win32 method GetTapeParameters. It usually works fine but for some reason, I  got the error 234 "More data is available" when reading one particular media. The default blocksize to read is 65536. If I read with a blocksize = blocksize * 16, the error doesn't occur anymore.

I specifically ask for a read of predetermined size, so I really don't understand why the data read is 16 times longer than expected. Am I missing something with the FileStream or with the Handle? Any help appreciated.

I'm working on Windows XP, with .Net 3.5, in C#, using Win32 API for communication with the LTO drive. Here are some pieces of code:

FileStream creation:

```
FileStream = new FileStream(TapeHandle, FileAccess.Read, (int)BlockSize, true);
```

TapeHandle creation:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string lpFileName_,
        EFileAccessType dwDesiredAccess_,
        uint dwShareMode_,
        IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes_,
        EFileCreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition_,
        EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes_,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile_);

internal enum EFileAttributes : uint
    {
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = 0x40000000,
        FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000,
        FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS = 0x10000000,
        FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x80000000,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 0x1,
    }

private SafeFileHandle CreateTapeHandle(string tapeName_)
    {
        SafeFileHandle result = Win32.CreateFile(
            tapeName_, Win32.EFileAccessType.GENERIC_READ, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 
            Win32.EFileCreationDisposition.OPEN_EXISTING,
            Win32.EFileAttributes.FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | Win32.EFileAttributes.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED |
            Win32.EFileAttributes.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | Win32.EFileAttributes.FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS |
            Win32.EFileAttributes.FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        if (result.IsInvalid)
            DisplayWin32Error(Resources.ERROR_DEVICE);

        return result;
    }
```

BeginRead:

```
internal byte[] Read()
    {
        DeviceStatus = Resources.DEVICE_READING;
        Debug.Assert(FileStream.CanRead);

        _stateObject.Buffer = new byte[BlockSize];
        _stateObject.Fs = FileStream;

        if (RestoreManager.Instance.RestoMode == RestoreManager.RestorationMode.Restoration)
            _stateObject.SetTimeOut();

        FileStream.BeginRead(
            _stateObject.Buffer, 0, _stateObject.Buffer.Length, EndReadAsyncCallback, _stateObject);

        WaitHandle.Reset();
        WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        FileStream.Flush();

        return _stateObject.Buffer;                                                                                      
    }
```

EndRead:

```
private void EndReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar_)
    {
        try
        {
            NbBytesRead = FileStream.EndRead(ar_);
            WaitHandle.Set();

            Debug.Assert(NbBytesRead <= BlockSize);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.LogError(Resources.ERROR_READ_FILE + " : " + e.Message);
            BackupReader.Instance.OnReadFailed(new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: It is the kind of accident that's likely to happen when you use FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING.  Do consider the possibility that GetTapeParameters() just gives you a default instead of the actual block size on the tape, even if you don't use it wrong.  Accidentally using GET_TAPE_DRIVE_INFORMATION is an easy mistake of course.  This just doesn't get put to the test much, programs normally use a big buffer.